# joining of tables based on the value of the fields

Tags: mysql

I was struck with a problem in joining of tables, there is a condition regarding the joining of two tables..
I've three tables let us assume it table1,table2 & table3,

```
table1
+---+
|id |
+---+

table2
+---------------+
|id | table1_id |
+---------------+

table3
+----------------------------+
| id | table1_id | table2_id |
+----------------------------+
```

Now, my master table is "table3", I need to join the master table with table1 & table2 in such a way that if the value of table2_id exists in the table3 then table2 should be joined with table2_id & similarly if table1_id exits then table1 will be joined with the table1_id,for eg: the entry into table3 is in this way

```
+----------------------------+
| id | table1_id | table2_id |
|  1 |     1     |     0     | 
|  2 |     0     |     1     |
+----------------------------+

for the value of id = 1,
table1_id exists & table2_id is zero, so table1 should be joined,
for the id = 2,
table2_id exists & table1_id is zero, so table2 should be joined,
if there is a case that both exists then table2 should be given the priority i.e, the table2 will be joined, can anyone make me out of this prb pls..
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about which tables are joining where. You appear to be saying that if there us a match between table2 and table3 then join table1 to table3, and if there us a match between table1 and table3 then join table2 to table3. You you possibly give a couple of example lines?

Comment: hi Kickstart i've modified  my question..pls have a luk

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make procedure in which you can put the conditions and execute the query as per your condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it using a LEFT JOIN and then sorting out the resulting columns required using a CASE statement.

As an example you could do something like this. Note you would need to repeat the CASE statement for each field you want to bring back.

```
SELECT table3.id, CASE table2.id IS NULL THEN table1.field ELSE table2.field END AS field
FROM table3
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table3.table2_id = table2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table3.table1_id = table1.id
```